# Java Swing- change the icon of the button that was pressed

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, cannot-find-symbol

In Java Swing, is there a quick way to change the icon of whichever button was pressed without having to write it separately for each button. Something like

```
event.getSource().setIcon( icon );
```

But this came up with a "cannot find symbol" error. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does *"But this did not work"* mean?

Comment: It came up with a compiler error

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that **will** work, but understand that `getSource()` returns an Object, and so you will need to cast, and cast *carefully*.

e.g.,

```
((JButton) event.getSource()).setIcon(icon);
```

If you're using a "switchboard" type of listener, where the listener is used on many different items (not really recommended that you do), then you'll need to check the type of the source *before* casting to avoid a casting exception.

If this doesn't work, you will need to be much more specific about "does not work" (not a very helpful phrase for us).

Comment: It works! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @DalekCaan99: you're welcome, but if you ask future questions, please improve your game. "does not work" == "not very helpful information". Show more [mcve] code, and be much more specific.

Comment: I'll accept your answer when it lets me

Comment: Ok. I'll remember that.

Comment: @DalekCaan99: don't worry. I answered as a community wiki and I will not gain any reputation from this answer. I felt that the quality of the question was somewhat low (to be honest), and so I did not want to gain rep from this guess of an answer.

Comment: ok. but thanks anyway for your help